# Thickness of the category of perfect complexes with finite length homology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, derived-categories, triangulated-categories

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian local ring and let $D(R)$ be the derived category of $R$-modules. Recall that a chain complex $C_\bullet$ of modules over $R$ is called *perfect* if it is isomorphic in $D(A)$ to a bounded complex of free and finitely generated $R$-modules. My question is this: is the category of perfect complexes *with finite length homology* a thick subcategory of $D(A)$? Actually I only need it to be triangulated. So if the answer to the previous question is negative, then I would like to know if the category of perfect complexes *with finite length homology* is a triangulated subcategory of $D(A)$? Any references for these will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this trivial? If you have a map between two bounded complexes of free and finitely generated R-modules, consider its cone, by definition, it is also a bounded complex  of free and finitely generated R-modules because every item of the complex is defined by  direct sum.

Comment: I think you are referring to the second question, correct? Because the mapping cone will also have homology of finite length. Is that what you are saying?

Comment: Yes. For the thickness, you may see here: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/perfect+chain+complex. Where says that perfect objects=compact objects. And compactness is a property stable under taking direct summand.

Comment: Modules of finite length are closed under homomorphic images, submodules, extensions, retracts... So yes.

Comment: Ok, I see it. Thanks. I made an error and thought that $R$ (regarded as a complex in $D(R)$) had homology of finite length.